# Multivariate Theory: How does the new mean only depend on the conditioned variable?

Tags: conditional-probability, gaussian-process, multivariate-normal-distribution

I'm doing some review of Gaussian Processes and Multivariate Normal Theory. I found a really helpful website [here](https://distill.pub/2019/visual-exploration-gaussian-processes/), but I have run into a snag. What does the author mean in the sentence below this picture:

[image]

The first sentence says that the new mean depends only on the conditioned variable, but the mean parameters above clearly reference both $X$ and $Y$. Is this saying that, in the case of $Y|X$, $X$ is known, so the only variable in the expression $\mu_Y$ is $Y$? I am assuming $Y$ is the *conditioned* variable in this case rather than $X$. Please confirm.

If that is true, then what does the author mean by the second phrase regarding the covariance matrix being independent from this variable? I don't see how the covariance matrix can be independent.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are random vectors such that $(X,Y)\sim \mathcal N(\mu,\Sigma)$,

where $\mu=(\mu_X,\mu_Y)^T$ and $\Sigma$ is partitioned as $\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma_{XX}& \Sigma_{XY} \\ \Sigma_{YX} & \Sigma_{YY} \end{pmatrix}$.

Then we have the well-known result stating that the distribution of $X$, given $Y=y$ (i.e. $X\mid Y=y$ ), is again multivariate normal with mean vector $\mu_X-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}(\mu_Y-y)$ and dispersion matrix $\Sigma_{XX}-\Sigma_{XY}\Sigma_{YY}^{-1}\Sigma_{YX}$.

That is, $\operatorname E(X\mid Y=y)$ depends on $y$ (as it should), but $\operatorname{Dispersion}(X\mid Y=y)$ is [independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoscedasticity) of $y$. The same thing happens for $Y\mid X$.

Comment: Ok, I think this makes sense. In the expression $X | Y = y$ we call $X$ the "conditioned variable", right? The mean vector is modified particularly by the distance of $y$ from $\mu_Y$ which is why it depends on $y$. Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: From your book's usage, they call $Y$ the 'conditioned variable' in $X\mid Y$. The mean vector of $X\mid Y=y$ is a function of $y$ (here $y$ is a particular realisation of $Y$), or equivalently, $E(X\mid Y)$ is a function of $Y$. The variance-covariance matrix of $X\mid Y$ is *not* a function of $Y$. That is what they are saying.